# How to merge two django models (tables) into one model (table)

Tags: mysql, django, database

I want to merge two django models and create single model. Let's suppose
I have first table Table A with some column and data.

```
Table A
--------------
col1   col2    col3    col4
x1     x2      x3      x4
y1     y2      y3      y4
```

and I have another table Table B with some column and data

```
Table B
--------------
col1   col2    col5    col6
x1     x2      p3      p4
y1     y2      p5      p6
```

in both the models (tables) I have few columns (here two column) similar and few columns are different. So I want to merge both the models (tables) and generate something like below:

```
Table C
-------------------------------------
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
x1      x2      x3      x4      p3      p4
y1      y2      y3      y4      p5      p6
```

I know when I will merge models and run make migration, django will surely create a migration and after migrating I would be able to create the above structure but I do not want to loose my data as it will be go on prod db.
It can be done easily with sql query on database but how to do with django????
Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: I suggest you to accept keni's answer

Answer (score 2):

A custom migrations should work.

1. You already have models A and B, so create model C with the fields you want from the two models.
2. Make a normal schema migration e.g. manage.py makemigrations ... and apply for any existing changes
3. Create a custom migration e.g. python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname (see link shared by @2ps
4. Edit the file generated above, I've added a sample data migration below.
5. rum manage.py migrate to apply the migration from step 4 above.
6. Drop models A and B if that's your wish, generate the migration and apply and you should be good.

   ...

   ```
   def merge_models_ab(apps, schema_editor):
       A = apps.get_model("app_name", "A")
       B = apps.get_model("app_name", "B")
       C = apps.get_model("app_name", "C")
       #come up with some interesting ways to join A and B
       #iterate over join and insert into C
       #C.objects.create(...)
   ```

   ...

   ```
   class Migrations(migrations.Migration):
       dependencies = [
           ('app_name', 'some_prev_migrations'),
       ]
       operations = [
           migrations.RunPython(merge_models_ab),
       ]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom data migration [(read the docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).